# How to logout with facebooker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I am using facebooker gem to connect facebook, but how to logout with it? thanks!

Comment: Wahtever you do, note that you'll be logging out the user from FB, which is highly surprising - and thus directly contradicting the basic UX rule, "don't surprise the user". I for one am very unhappy when various apps log me out of FB when attempting to only log out from that app.

Comment: you mean there is no need to logout user from FB? I think it is reasonable

Comment: But I notice that, when I hava logged out from FB, the facebook session is still there in my site

Answer (score 0):

You can't log a user out of a Facebook session from server side code.  The only way is to use the Javascript SDK and call FB.logout. Something like this should work:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({appId: 'YOUR APP ID', status : true, cookie : true, xfbml  : true});
  FB.logout(function(response) {});
</script>
```